# Safely wake thread in Ruby

Tags: ruby, multithreading, concurrency, mutex

I need to have a thread to stop itself and then be woken up by another thread. The problem I have is that I can't find a good solution that is completely foolproof. The code I have now looks something like this:

```
def initialize
  @data_lock = Mutex.new
  @closed = false
end

def get_response
  @data_lock.synchronize do
    @blocked_thread = Thread.current
  end
  # This loop is a safe guard against accidental wakeup of thread
  loop do
    @data_lock.synchronize do
      if @closed
        return @response
      end
    end
    # FIXME: If context switch happens here the thread will be permanently frozen.
    Thread.stop  # Stop current thread and wait for call to close()
  end
end


def close(response)
  @data_lock.synchronize do
    @closed = true
    @response = response
    Thread.pass  # An attempt at minimizing the risk of permanently freezing threads
    if @blocked_thread.is_a? Thread and @blocked_thread.status == 'sleep'
      @blocked_thread.wakeup
    end
  end
end
```

The way it's supposed to work is that a call to get_response will block the current thread and when another thread calls close() the first thread should be woken up and return the value sent through @response.

This should work in all circumstances except in the rare case that a second thread calls close before the first thread has stopped and there's a context switch just before the first thread stops. How can I remove this (granted very unlikely) possibility?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to communicate with a thread uses a [Thread#Queue](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Queue.html) object.  Thread#Queue is a thread-safe FIFO queue.

```
require "thread"

@queue = Queue.new
```

When the tread wants to block until signaled, it reads from the queue.  The thread will stop while the queue is empty:

```
@queue.deq
```

To awaken the thread, write something into the queue:

```
@queue.enq :wakeup
```

Here, we just threw a symbol into the queue.  But you can also write things into the queue that you want the thread to process.  For example, if a thread is processing URLs, it can retrieve them from the queue:

```
loop do
  url = @queue.deq
  # process the url
end
```

And some other thread can add URLs to the queue:

```
@queue.enq "http://stackoverflow.com"
@queue.enq "http://meta.stackoverflow.com"
```

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I needed!

Comment: @AndreasHagelberg I'm delighted that it was helpful!  If you want, you can click on the up-triangle to vote it up (it's how we show appreciation around here).  There is also a checkmark that you can click to show that this was the best answered that helped you.

Comment: I've already upvoted it, but unfortunately I don't have enough reputation to have it publicly visible yet. The checkmark I missed though, but I've checked it now.

Comment: @AndreasHagelberg Interesting...  I didn't know that upvotes could be invisible.  Thanks for the checkmark, and welcome to SO!